# Storing regularly used Grails commands for later use in NetBeans?

Tags: unit-testing, grails, netbeans

I regularly use **right mouse button** > "*Run/Debug Grails Command...*" from within NetBeans.

When I do so, it's cumbersome b/c I have to wait for "*Reloading Grails commands...*", then I have to choose the command and manually type all parameters e.g. "`unit:spock -coverage ExampleController`".

I'll have to compose the commands everytime I restart NetBeans.

1. Is there a **better solution to this**?
2. Also, everytime I run "test-app" complete Grails restarts - is it possible to **leave Grails running and just execute the tests in question via a click again**, and again, and again ... ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the help of [david](https://stackoverflow.com/users/120296/david), I can now answer my question #2:

When clicking **right mouse button** > "*Run/Debug Grails Command...*" from within NetBeans, simply double-click "*interactive*" from the list.

Then, in the new shell, type the test you want to run without `grails`. E.g. only `test-app unit:spock -coverage ExampleController`

Everytime you want to execute the test again **just hit ENTER** within the shell/console.

Note that Grails won't be able to handle certain changes correctly. In this case you willl most likely see unexpected exceptions and the like.

If that happens, just **close the shell**, **clean** the project, rinse & repeat.